# Hyperref problems in Beamer when using notes

Tags: beamer, hyperref, notes

**Update and MWE added**

I'm working with Beamer for the first time, and I want to use notes pages to prompt myself. However, when I turn them on, either by using either `\documentclass[notes]{beamer}` or `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}`, most items that should produce a hyperlink, e.g. sections, citations, section links, produces pdflatex errors to the effect of `destination with the same identifier has already been used`.

The following is a MWE example, which I'm compiling with MikTeX 2.9 (with recently updated packages) on Windows 7. You can see there are several different ways I might want to incorporate notes. In this MWE, options 2-4 give warnings and bad links, while in my full document, option 1 does as well. In this MWE, if I add a bibliography using BibTeX, option 1 will then give link errors on the citations as well.

```
% In this MWE, options 2-4 all cause hyperlink problems. In my full presentation, option 1 does as well. 
% The only one that works is option 5, which had no notes in any form. 

%% 1. DUAL-DISPLAY NOTES:
%\documentclass[hyperref={bookmarks=false}]{beamer}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}

% 2. NOTES ON SEPARATE SLIDES:
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}

% 3. NOTES ONLY:
%\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}

% 4. HANDOUTS:
%\documentclass[handout,notes]{beamer}

% 5. NO NOTES: ONLY ONE THAT BUILDS WITHOUT WARNINGS
%\documentclass[hide notes]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title[Pres\hspace{2em}\insertframenumber/
\inserttotalframenumber]{My Presentation}
\author[Me Me] {Me}
\institute[Univ.]{University}
\date[Sep. 14, 2011]{September 14$^{\text{th}}$, 2011}

% Makes TOC show at beginning og each section:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
    \note{}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\note{}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\note{}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{A content frame }
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Here is some content.
                \note[item]{And here is a related note.}
        \item More content.
                    \note[item]{Another note. }
        \item Yet more content.
                    \note[item]{Yet again a note.}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A second content frame}
\begin{itemize}
        \uncover<1->{
        \item Indented content:
        \begin{itemize}
                \item First piece.
                \note[item]<1->{Note about first piece. }
        \end{itemize}
        }
        \uncover<2->{
        \item More content.
        \begin{itemize}
                \item More indented content.
                \note[item]<2-> {Note about this second piece of content. }
        }
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My question is, is it possible to have working hyperlinks when using note pages, or does the inherent modifications to the page numbering by addition of notes preclude this? I'm hoping I've just loaded some packages in the wrong order or something here.

**Update**

As per percusse's answer below, for options 2-4, the problem is fixed by using the newer notes options, e.g. `show notes` instead of just `notes`, as follows:

```
%% 1. DUAL-DISPLAY NOTES:
%\documentclass[hyperref={bookmarks=false}]{beamer}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}

% 2. NOTES ON SEPARATE SLIDES:
\documentclass[show notes]{beamer}

% 3. NOTES ONLY:
%\documentclass[show only notes]{beamer}

% 4. HANDOUTS:
%\documentclass[handout,show notes]{beamer}

% 5. NO NOTES: ONLY ONE THAT BUILDS WITHOUT WARNINGS
%\documentclass[hide notes]{beamer}
```

However, they persist with Option 1 (dual-display). This seems related to the mini slide that gets inserted in the upper-right of the notes page; apparently that mini slide has duplicates of the labels in the main slide. One solutions for this is to use `show notes on second screen=right` instead so the right slide gets the broken links and the left one (presentation slide) gets working ones.

Another partial solution that removes the warnings is to remove that mini-slide from the notes pages in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty` by removing the following lines under `\defbeamertemplate*{note page}{default}`:

```
  \hfill\insertslideintonotes{0.5}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip0pt%
  \vskip-0.25\paperheight%
  \nointerlineskip
```

Then, Option 1 compiles with no warnings, but the various navigation links in the presentation slide (e.g. outline at top of slides, navigation keys at bottom right) still do not work.

So, my **updated (refined) question is**, is it possible to build with the option `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}` and still have working links in the presentation slides?

Comment: Can you provide a **full** working example, please?  That means that we need a complete document that will display the errors.  I just tried guessing some document contents and didn't get any errors so presumably I didn't guess correctly.

Comment: Just to be clear: You have about 30 lines of own code in your document that you want us to debug? **MWE** please.

Comment: I will try to put together a MWE tonight. Thanks guys.

Comment: Hi guys, I've added a MWE now so I'm curious to see if you get the build errors I am getting. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Does the MWE I've added reproduce for you the issues I described?

Comment: You MWE (as-is; option 2) compiles without errors. There are some **warnings**, but the hyperlinks are fine. Does yours actually produce an error?

Comment: Okay, so reading this again, it seems like you are interested in having hyperlinks from the notes to the actual presentation? This is provided by the tree a the top of each note. The actual "presentation thumbnail" (upper right) is void of any links. Do you want links in this thumbnail?

Comment: @Werner: as per the comments on percusse's answer, the problem appears to be that the mini preview does in fact have labels at least when the option `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}` is used, resulting in duplicate label issues, and links not actually working. I don't care about links from the notes pages themselves, but I'd like links on the presentation slides to work, which they do not when option `left` is used, but do when option `right` is used.

Comment: @Werner: I've updated my question if you have a chance to look at it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried all options and as it complains, you are simply using obsolete versions of the `notes` option and make sure that you compile twice to be sure about the warnings. The cases below are fully working without any errors or warnings on Win7 64bit, Texniccenter 2 Alpha3, Miktex 2.9.

```
% 2. NOTES ON SEPARATE SLIDES:
\documentclass[show notes]{beamer}

% 3. NOTES ONLY:
\documentclass[show only notes]{beamer}

% 4. HANDOUTS:
\documentclass[handout,show notes]{beamer}
```

I have tried adding new sections and everything (hyperlinks etc.) looks working. I have used the example bibliography on page 102 of the manual (v.3.12) and it is also working without any errors and mistakes. Please edit your question further if you feel that there is still something that does not work.

Here is what I have used, just in case:

```
%% 1. DUAL-DISPLAY NOTES:
%\documentclass[
                                                        %hyperref={bookmarks=false}
                                                        %]{beamer}
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}

% 2. NOTES ON SEPARATE SLIDES:
\documentclass[show notes]{beamer}

% 3. NOTES ONLY:
%\documentclass[show only notes]{beamer}

% 4. HANDOUTS:
%\documentclass[handout,show notes]{beamer}

% 5. NO NOTES: ONLY ONE THAT BUILDS WITHOUT WARNINGS
%\documentclass[hide notes]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title[Pres\hspace{2em}\insertframenumber/
\inserttotalframenumber]{My Presentation}
\author[Me Me] {Me}
\institute[Univ.]{University}
\date[Sep. 14, 2011]{September 14$^{\text{th}}$, 2011}

% Makes TOC show at beginning og each section:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
    \note{}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\note{}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\note{}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{A content frame }
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Here is some content.
                \note[item]{And here is a related note.}
        \item More content.
                    \note[item]{Another note. }
        \item Yet more content.
                    \note[item]{Yet again a note.}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A second content frame}
\begin{itemize}
        \uncover<1->{
        \item Indented content:
        \begin{itemize}
                \item First piece.
                \note[item]<1->{Note about first piece. }
        \end{itemize}
        }
        \uncover<2->{
        \item More content.
        \begin{itemize}
                \item More indented content.
                \note[item]<2-> {Note about this second piece of content. }
        }
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{citation}it cites \cite{Salomaa1973}\end{block}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{block1}content 1\end{block}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{block 2}content 2\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{Dijkstra, 1982}
\bibitem[Salomaa, 1973]{Salomaa1973}
A.~Salomaa.
\newblock {\em Formal Languages}.
\newblock Academic Press, 1973.
\bibitem[Dijkstra, 1982]{Dijkstra1982}
E.~Dijkstra.
102
\newblock Smoothsort, an alternative for sorting in situ.
\newblock {\em Science of Computer Programming}, 1(3):223--233, 1982.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** It turns out that I did not try it with option 1 afterwards. I was able to reproduce the warnings. I will try to see if I can come up with something.

**EDIT2:** I have switched the location of the presentation and the notes and at least it works as it should. The problem I am guessing is that hyperref only defines hyperlinks for the part on the left and then when creating that small minipage at the corner of the notes, it gets confused since they are defined already on the body of the presentation.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={bookmarks=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}
```

this still gives you the warning but the presentation works fine.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start. So, just to be clear, the problem is that the small sample of the slide on the notes page contains the same labels as the full-size slide, and this is where the duplicate label warning are coming from? I notice that if I use `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
`, most of the links work fine, but with `left`, they continue to malfunction. Is there a way to either a) strip the labels out of that mini-page but otherwise keep it the same (best option), or b) remove the mini-page from the notes page (fall-back option)? Thanks.

Comment: since the mini slide on the notes page seems partly responsible for this problem, I tried removing by commenting out the lines `\hfill\insertslideintonotes{0.5}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip0pt%`, `\vskip-0.25\paperheight%`, and `\nointerlineskip` in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty` under `\defbeamertemplate*{note page}{default}`, and this removed the warnings, but I still get no links on the presentation slides, when using `show notes on second screen=left`, e.g. the outline at the top of the slides does not have links, and the navigation buttons do not work.

Comment: I've updated my question if you have a chance to look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: @SSilk I will definitely have a look but it seems that it might get quickly beyond my Tex skills. We should still keep an eye on other sources of the problem since we did not pinpoint exactly the cause. But I have to say your argument is pretty nice. Let me create some additional time just to work on this. And I hope one of our wizards on Tex.SE can shed some light too.

Comment: @SSilk And as a super-pragmatic temporary solution, you can identify your main display(projector, beamer etc.) on Windows as the one on right and still use the `...second screen= right` option for the dual displays. I know it is a horrible hack but might save the day if you are in a bit of rush.

Comment: I'd already hit on the idea of swapping laptop and projector location left to right. It doesn't appear any other answers are forthcoming, so I've awarded the bounty. Overall, this behaviour feels like a Beamer bug, and if it's not, then this behaviour should at least be documented. If you have any further thoughts on this problem, I'd still like to hear them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SSilk Thanks, I did some reading. I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Did anybody come up with a solution to this?? I posted this question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327299/beamer-presentation-with-notes-warning-destination-with-the-same-identifier), some months back, and still nothing...