# Links in beamer theme Warsaw don't work if notes are shown and title is set

Tags: beamer, links

I wonder that I found this issue nowhere in the web. For me this occurs since years over different versions. Now I took the time to figure out under which conditions it happens. I would be very happy if someone could help me or even tell me where I can find help.

Under the conditions:

- Documentclass `beamer`
- Theme `Warsaw`
- Option `show notes on second screen`
- Title is set

The links generated by section and subsection set by the Warsaw theme (in the top, not the standard `beamer` links) are not working. Most time it happens nothing or leading to a wrong page, when pressing. If you hide the notes or delete the title, it works. Here a short example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}
\title{How to number the ...?‎} 
\author{My name‎} 
\date{06‎.06.2005} 
\begin{frame}‎
‎\titlepage‎
‎\end{frame}‎‎‎
\section{First}
\begin{frame}
First Frame
\end{frame}
\section{Second}
\begin{frame}
Second Frame
\end{frame}
\section{Third}
\begin{frame}
Third Frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Because until now no one has an idea how to solve it and it looks like a bug, I reported it [here](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/176). But I don't think that this will be a solution, because there are a lot of bugs open from 2010. Is there an alternative to beamer package?

Comment: Hi to display a code section, just indent it by 4 spaces, or use the `{}` icon in the edit bar, see the edit above.

Comment: Hmm, tried this. But it resulted in the same... I will try it again next time. Thanks

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand exactly the problem, however I remember a similar problem [in this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29219/3235) that we failed to find a solution. I am not sure if it is relevant but can you have a look?

Comment: Yes, this must belong to the same problem. What I saw he didn't mention my biggest problem: That the section / subsection links created in the top are not working (simply try it if you don't understand). But I also have the same warning like him with other links when I turn on notes ("destination with same identifier .... "). So I think this might belong to the same error.

Comment: I tried his workarounds. It really seems to be the same problem. If I use "show notes" it works. But I need notes on second screen :-/ His solution to use the right screen sadly only works for the other links. The section, subsection links are klickable but don't respond like they should (as in my example).

Comment: I will see if I can find out what is up here. Unfortunately, `beamer` is pretty complex and the original author no longer looks after it. I fix bugs that I can, but it's non-trivial (the interactions in the code are not straight-forward to follow).

Comment: Very cool, thanks. If you see by chance a workaround, please share it. In the moment I have every day a presentation where this annoys every day.

Comment: Hello, the referenced previous question was mine. The problem was slightly different. That problem was largely resolved by removing the minipage from the notes pages. However, I still get bad links in the navigation bar on the actual slides, which is what I think Wolfgang is talking about. I do not get compiler warnings, but many of the nav bar links, instead of taking me to the intended section will instead take me to the title slide. This problem only occurs when using notes. If I compile without notes, the links all seem fine.

Answer (score 5):

(A comment of sorts, but I guess also an answer.)

The issue here is due to the way notes are shown on a second screen, which uses the `pgfpages` package. The issue arises because of the way the latter deals with multiple pages, and that leads onto how the PDF specification deals with hyperlinks. Thus the issue is not the theme as such:  it is just that it shows up when using a theme which inserts the problematic links.

As a result, this really is not something that is fixable at the `beamer` end, at least without a complete re-write of large parts of the code. I'm not about to do that as it will break far more things than it fixes.

Comment: Can you think of any workaround to enable notes and links? Thanks