# Beamer presentation with notes: navigation does not work properly and "destination with the same identifier" warnings show up

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, links, navigation, notes

I am refloating a long-standing Beamer problem and will put a good bounty to it, to see if we can all solve this problem once and for all...

I am following on a previous question I posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327299/beamer-presentation-with-notes-warning-destination-with-the-same-identifier), and an [old post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29219/hyperref-problems-in-beamer-when-using-notes) that never got a proper answer, and adding some more information and problems detected just recently.

The problems are related to the navigation links in **Beamer presentations WITH NOTES**.

1. If you try to show your **notes on the left**, navigation links on the top of slides just plain do not work.
2. If you do like I did and switch **notes to the right**, the links on top work.

BUT STILL WE RUN INTO THE FOLLOWING PROBLEMS:

- Links in the **table of contents** do not work at all.
- You get infinite amounts of the following **warnings** (one per slide):

> destination with the same identifier * has been already used, duplicate ignored

I think this is a really big problem with Beamer, I do not know if it is a bug or it can be solved somehow...

Turning off the links is not an option; though we will remove the warnings, the main reason why some of us use Beamer is for the awesome navigation that takes us quickly to a slide in a big presentation during the questions round.

***It would be of great advantage if the navigation feature could be used together with the ability to add notes next to the slides... In fact, I do not understand why this is not possible.***

I gave up trying to add the notes on the left, so let's try to make everything work at least with the notes on the right...

With notes on the right, navigation links on top of slides work, but we still need to make navigation in table of contents work too, and get rid of those terribly annoying warnings.

This is a MWE to start playing with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}%better notes on right

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Singapore}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage  
\note{
    Notes for the title page
}
\end{frame}


\section*{Outline}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents

\note{
    Notes for the table of contents
}
\end{frame}


\section{Frame 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with notes 1}
    FIRST FRAME CONTENTS

\note{
    Notes for the first frame
}
\end{frame}


\section{Frame 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with notes 2}
    SECOND FRAME CONTENTS
\note{
    Notes for the second frame
}
\end{frame}


\section{Frame 3}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame with notes 3}
    SECOND FRAME CONTENTS
    \note{
        Notes for the third frame
    }
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**EXTRA BONUS POINTS IF YOU ARE ABLE TO MAKE NAVIGATION WORK IN HANDOUT FORMAT TOO, WHERE NAVIGATION DOES NOT WORK AT ALL!
Just use:**

```
 \documentclass[handout]{beamer}
 \usepackage{pgfpages}
 \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
 \setbeameroption{show notes}
```

Comment: Just wanted to comment on "Links in the table of contents do not work at all." This is not true for me, the links do work. I have `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux)`, `beamer.cls    2015/01/05 3.36` and `pgfpages.sty    2011/01/05`.

Comment: The manual gives a very clear answer: **Using pgfpages will destroy hyperlinks** ... **It is unlikely that this will change in the foreseeable future**.

Comment: And no patch or anything available? It is what it is then?

Comment: At least a way to avoid the warnings?

Comment: Links work fine in `handout` mode. As others say, it is the use of `pgfpages` which destroys the links.

Comment: So can all this be accomplished without using pgfpages? How?

Comment: I confirm that with the code above and under Ubuntu 16.04 and Texlive 2015 links do not work anywhere (not ToC and not top bar navigation) in handout mode

Comment: I also confirm that with the code above with the notes on the right, ToC links do not work under Ubuntu 16.04 and Texlive 2015

Comment: Is the exact same code working for you guys? With pgfpages and all? What about the warnings? What is your exact configuration?

Comment: You have to use `@` to ping particular people, if you want to address them. No, the links do not work with `pgfpages`. That is expected. It does, however, work in `handout` mode.

Answer (score 7):

I added a bug report to the beamer issue tracker regarding the destination warnings: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/370.

Regarding links and toc one can only quote the documentation of pgfpages (in pgfmanual.pdf)

> A word of warning: using pgfpages *will destroy hyperlinks*. Actually,
>   the hyperlinks are not destroyed, only they will appear at totally
>   wrong positions on the final output. This is due to a fundamental flaw
>   in the pdf specification: In pdf the bounding rectangle of a hyperlink
>   is given in “absolute page coordinates” and translations or rotations
>   do not affect them. Thus, the transformations applied by pgfpages to
>   put the pages where you want them are (cannot, even) be applied to the
>   coordinates of hyperlinks. It is unlikely that this will change in the
>   foreseeable future.

That's imho why links works more or less ok on the main slide when you put the notes on the right (it does for me when I compile with a current texlive live, including the outlines): As pgfpages inserts the notes into the main slide on the right the absolutes coordinate are not changed. If you put the notes on the left and hover with your mouse around the notes you will see that the links are there.

With handouts **with 2 on 1** layout there is imho no chance to get working links. Here both pages are reinserted in a third and this looses anotations anyway (in addition to the coordinate problem which would exist here too).

Comment: So this means there's nothing to change in my code? no other way to get the same without pgfpages? We just have to deal with this? That's actually what I thought, but people in the comments say it works for them, so I got confused...

Comment: Well your example with notes on the right works fine for -- including the links in the outline and the bookmarks. Tested with TL16 and adobe reader on windows.  Regarding handout mode there has been perhaps a confusing: handout alone could work (I didn't try), handout with "2 on 1" layout won't.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot post a comment, but if the pgfpages package is the problem you could use [PDFjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) in the shell.

Comment: I really seriously doubt that this will in anyway help. It is just a wrapper around `pdfpages` which will also lose or break hyperlinks. See the documentation.